# How to protect a single database row / Model instance?

Tags: django, postgresql

We have customers, and `Customer` objects. One of these, which I was creating with a migration, was `Customer( account='INTERNAL' ...)` as a placeholder for when we manufacture stuff for internal consumption.

Customers come and go, so the objects need to be deletable. But this single row must not be deleted.

What is the best way to stop it getting accidentally deleted? I can replace all instances of `Customer.objects.get(account='INTERNAL')` with  `get_or_create` so it is self-resurrecting, but it feels like storing up trouble for the future if there are ForeignKey references to it and then it gets deleted. (It can't be Models.PROTECT, because other customers *can* be  deleted).

Tagged **[postgresql]**, because that's what we use. I suspect there might be a way to use database functionality to do what I want, but I'd appreciate it if the answer showed how to write doing that  as a Django migration (if that's possible). I know more about Django than SQL and Postgres extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `on_delete=models.PROTECT` to created related record that will prevent deletion of the Customer until it exists

Create special model for this case

```
class CustomerDeleteProtection(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

When you will try to remove related customer it will raise DB error

Comment: Simple, elegant, and completely what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to cover this requirement by supporting authorization (and eventually authentication). And this can be done at a DBMS level (PostgreSQL) or API level.

Example: in your API you design/develop two following methods:

- a delete-external-customers method and a wide audience is entitled to invoke this method
- a delete-internal-customer(s) method and only a limited (and authenticated) audience is entitle to invoke this method

At a DBMS level, I'm inclined to believe you can establish this as well with grants and/or views.

Answer (score -1):

you can add an extra property for eg: customer_type and assign value "internal" for row which must not be deleted and some other value for other customers. When deleting, you can check this column.

Comment: The question is asking for a way "to stop it from getting _accidentally_ deleted". The approach "When deleting, you can check this column." does not prevent any such accidents.